# jQuery wrap and appendTo doesn't lead in expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap some HTML content inside a div container and then append a span to that container. But I can't figure out why the appended span doesn't appear.

So I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 
    var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>');
 $('.target').wrap($container);
   
    $label = $('<span class="duration-label">Hi there</span>');
 $label.appendTo($container);
});
```

```css
.target {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target">
    <span>This is some unimportant text</span>
</div>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I don't know if you noticed my answer, just to let you know I explained why `wrap` works this way in case you're wondering...

Comment: @Amit I appreciate that. I just picked the T.J. Crowder's answer first. Both answers are similar and both are right.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I wanted to draw your attention to the extra info there. I hope that helps you further understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) makes a **copy** of the wrapper you give it, it doesn't use the one you give it directly. You're appending to the one you gave it.

Instead, use the one you wrapped around the content:

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  // Wrap .target with the div, and get a reference to
  // the newly-created wrapper
  var $container =
          $('.target')
              .wrap('<div class="container"></div>')
              .parent();

  // Add a label to it
  var $label = $('<span class="duration-label">Hi there</span>');
  $label.appendTo($container);
});
```

```css
.target {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target">
  <span>This is some unimportant text</span>
</div>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

---

Side note: Your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you didn't declare `$label`. It's important to declare your variables. You can use strict mode to have the JavaScript engine keep you from creating globals implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `$container` refers to variable and not object of wrapped element. You need to get the object or use relevant selector to append to container element :

```
$label.appendTo('.container');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35rbmp18/)**

Comment: It will, of course, be a bit of a problem if there are any *other* `.container` elements on the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sure they will. solution provided by you is more promising.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the `.wrap()` method wraps ***each*** element in the set of matched elements with a new element structure - copies of `$container`.

`$container` itself is not the wrapping element, it's just a "template" for wrapping elements, so you need to grab the actual element(s) if you want to further manipulate them.

This of course is simple to understand once you consider the fact that after the call there can be more then 1 such element.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>');
  var $wrappingContainer = $('.target').wrap($container).parent();

  // sanity check:
  if($container[0] == $wrappingContainer[0]) {
    alert('Same object?!?!'); // Should not happen
  }

  $label = $('<span class="duration-label">Hi there</span>');
  $label.appendTo($wrappingContainer);
});
```

```css
.target {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target">
  <span>This is some unimportant text</span>
</div>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```